# Error on boot : dev/sda6 UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: boot, 18.04, fsck

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda6: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda6 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.27.2(Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I earlier faced this problem which I solved by simply writing `fsck /dev/sdax`. Later on I faced unable to mount boot with something error (0,0), so I reinstalled Ubuntu again, but unluckily I updated and again I ended up with this.

This time when I run `fsck /dev/sda7` it shows

```
fsck: error2 (no such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda7
```

How to fix this?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

At the initfamfs prompt, type `fsck -fy /dev/sda6`.

You may also have a bad `/boot/initrd.img*` file if problems continue.

If you dual-boot with Windows, and have a Windows driver that reads/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions, remove it asap, as it's corrupting your Ubuntu.